# Can I dissociate my username from a question?

Tags: support

I made a "burner" account to ask a question on this exchange, since I wanted to keep it separate from my personal account. However, upon completing email verification, it seems to be linked to my account now.

Is there a way to dissociate a question from my account after it's been linked?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just flag your own post as "in need of moderator intervention," make your request in the text box, and we'll take a look.

Note, we do try to discourage this because the moderators actually have to forward the request to the SE employees, and we want to be respectful of their time (among other downsides as described in the post that Bryan linked). But we do approve these as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can request dissociation through the Contact link at the bottom of the page, but see [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa) for some of the limits and things to consider first.